# Удалить или изменить параметр src по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как изменить или удалить параметр `src` по клику? При открытии скрытого блока включается видео, но при закрытии оно продолжает воспроизводиться.

Этим кодом я запускаю видео. Подскажите, как при закрытии окна его остановить.

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-video', function() {
  var $video = $('#video'),
  src = $video.attr('src');
  $video.attr('src', src + '?autoplay=1');
});
```

Пробовал добавить при клике на кнопку

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-video', function() {
  var $video = $('#video'),
  src = $video.attr('src');
  $video.attr('src', src + '?pause=1');
});
```

Но при повторном открытии видео не запускается, в ссылке остаются оба параметра, как удалить `?autoplay=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заранее очищать ссылку от переменных

```js
$(document).on('click', '.open-video', function() {
  var $video = $('#video'),
      src = $video.attr('src').replace(/^(.+)\?.+$/, '$1');
      
  $video.attr('src', src + '?pause=1');
  
  console.log( $video.attr('src') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video src="video.mp4" id="video"></video>

<button class="open-video">Изменить</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для запуска видео используйте:

```
$video.get(0).play()
```

Для паузы:

```
$video.get(0).pause()
```

Заметьте, что `play()`  и `pause()` это не функции jQuery, поэтому чтобы перейти в DOM-элемент используется `get()`

Comment: Ну можно не только `get` указывать, а ещё и просто установить `[n]`